# WPF/MVVM binding CheckBox in ListBoxItem template to SelectedItem property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, checkedlistbox

I am building a WPF application (.NET 4.0), and I have the following situation:

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="48"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <!-- ... -->
                <CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                        <!-- Something here that behaves like SelectedItem binding -->
                    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                </CheckBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

- The ItemSource of the ListBox is bound to an ObservableCollection<>.
- The SelectedItem of the ListBox is bound to a SelectedItem property
  of the ViewModel.

However, when the ViewModel.SelectedItem is updated, a bit of a long-running (2-3s) asynchronous task is kicked off. 
It is way too easy to queue up a large numer of asynchronous task by simply selecting different items in the list box, so I am looking into binding ViewModel.SelectedItem to a CheckBox instead (included in the ItemTemplate).

I am fairly new to WPF, but in Forms I would have attached an event handler and written some long and ugly code to de-check all items but the one that triggered the event, then update the property programmatically.

In WPF I am hoping that there is some nicer solution, I have looked into using a ValueConverter, but I can't figure out how to bind to the parent View-Model (that has the ObservableCollection<>).

If anyone has encountered similar requirements, I would really appreciate some pointers.

Cheers!

./Fredrik

Comment: Wouldn't it be equally easy to queue up a large number of asynchronous tasks by repeatedly clicking the checkboxes? I guess what you need is a mechanism that cancels the currently running task when a new one is started. And you may consider to do a delayed start of the task, instead of doing it immediately when the selected item changes.

Comment: Hi Clemens, thans for responding! Yes, it would, but it shouldn't be too hard to prevent changes to the checked state while an asynchronous task is running. I tried the same by disabling the ListBox when the task was running, but that was too ugly. The benefit with the added CheckBox is that selection within the ListBox is separated from the task, allowing the user to browse around the list box while the task is running.

Comment: You may also think of having a dedicated button outside the listbox (instead of all the checkboxes) to start a task on the currently selected item. That would not only be easier to implement, but may also lead to a more intuitive UI.

Comment: A good suggestion, that is the fallback I am using at the moment. I would prefer the Chckbox though, since the checked state provides information on "what did I select". 
With the button I will have to add a Label or something  to indicate what item was selected when the button was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that doesn't resort to processing the checked states in code-behind, so I'm going to document it for posterity.

The first trick is to use `RadioButton` instead, with and associated `GroupName`. Radio buttons within the same group will automatically ensure that only one of them is checked at any given time, which avoids the issue with manually managing the checked states.

The second trick is to bind a `CommandParameter` to the radio buttons `DataContext`.

```
<RadioButton
    Name="rdbSelected"
    GroupName="itemsRadioGroup"
    Command="{Binding 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},
        Path=DataContext.SelectItemCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
        Path=DataContext}"/>
```

The radio buttons command fires on every click, not just when it is checked, but we get away with this because unlike `CheckBox`it is not possible to un-check a radio button, so double-clicking the radio button will only confirm the `SelecedItem`.

If the `SelectedItem` property fires a `PropertyChanged` event, it may be advisable to have the command handler check whether it is in fact setting a new value, or just repeating the previous one:

```
RelayCommand<object> cmd = new RelayCommand<object>(
    (o) =>
    {
       if (this.SelectedItem != o)
           this.SelectedItem = o;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can Bind the CheckBox to the Command to VM  and the command will Fire when CheckBox is Selected/DeSelected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response!

Now we are closing in. The command would let me set SelectedItem programmatically, but there are multiple items in the ListBox, each templated with a CheckBox.
How would I de-check the other CheckBoxes, retaining the SelectionMode Single behavior?

Cheers!

Comment: You can Decheck them in ViewModel and the changes will be reflected on UI

Comment: Like you have List of Boolean Binded to ISelected of those CheckBoxes and When you want to Decheck all them then just set all values in list false and set Selected Item in that List true. Its all about how good you do the logic in VM

Comment: True, that would be a comfortable (for me) way to go, as it is similar to the Forms way.
My ListBoxItems are already bound directly to Model business objects, but I could create a wrapper like ListBoxItemWrapper<T> where T would be "BusinessObject". It would require some coding for what seems like a fairly straight-forward data binding scenario, but it is certainly one solution. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind isselected property of  ListBoxItem  to checkbox through TemplateBinding.

Comment: Hi Nakul, thanks for responding!

Wouldn't that actually change the ListBox selection along with with the checked state (at least for two-way binding). My purpouse here is to have a single property SelectedItem in the View-Model reflect which (single) item in a ListBox is checked.
Cheers!